# How to display images in templates and where to place that image?

Tags: magento-1.8, theme

In my template I want to display an image.

1. How can I do it?
2. Where do I place my image?
3. How can the path of to image be specified in template file (pattern)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options here.
If the image must be theme dependent just put the image in `skin/frontend/{package}/{theme}/images/image.jpg` and put this in your template:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/image.jpg')?>" alt="" />
```

If the image should be the same for all themes just place it in the media folder. You can even use a subfolder to for easier management.   `media/some_folder/image.jpg`. Then add this to your template:

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'some_folder/image.jpg')?>" alt="" />
```